# clear cookies in phonegap / disable phonegap from using cookies

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cookies

I am currently making a login system for my mobile application. When i log in to my server, mu server sends back a JSESSIONID, which i can use to authenticate myself for furthers calls. The problem I am experiencing here is that PhoneGap seems to automatically save this cookie without me asking to. This way, i cant provide a log out feature since PhoneGap is saving the cookie and always sending it back to de server in each call I make.... I'm using `xmlhttp` requests.
I either want a way to delete this cookie, or a way to disable PhoneGap from saving the cookie in the first place, and handle the session-cookie myself.
I've been looking to find this cookie but i cant seem to find it. 
Anyone got an idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create the class (CacheCleaner.java file) in the package "org.apache.cordova.plugins"

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugins;

            import java.io.File;

            import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
            import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
            import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
            import org.json.JSONArray;

            import android.util.Log;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class CacheCleaner extends CordovaPlugin {

                public static final String LOG_PROV = "PhoneGapLog";
                public static final String LOG_NAME = "CacheCleaner Plugin";

                @Override
                public boolean execute(final String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
                    if (action.equals("del")) {
                        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    final File dir = cordova.getActivity().getCacheDir();
                                    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                                        deleteDir(dir);
                                        showToast("Cache is deleted.","short");
                                    }
                                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e(LOG_PROV, LOG_NAME + ": Error: " + PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
                                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        Log.e(LOG_PROV, LOG_NAME + ": Error: " + PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
                        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION));
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                public static boolean deleteDir(final File dir) {
                    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                        final String[] children = dir.list();
                        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                            final boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                            if (!success) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (dir != null && dir.isFile()) {
                        dir.delete();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                private void showToast(final String message, final String duration) {
                    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(duration.equals("long")) {
                                Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Create the javascript file "cachecleaner.js"

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/cachecleaner", function (require, exports, module) {
                var exec = require("cordova/exec");
              module.exports = {
                    del: function (win, fail) {
                    exec(win, fail, "CacheCleaner", "del", []);
                    }
                };
            });
```

Add the following line to the "config.xml" file in your res folder of your Android project.

```
<feature name="Share"><param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.CacheCleaner" /></feature>
```

use this code in your html file, when click on any button  cache is clear.

use this function :-

```
 $(document).on('click','.abs',function(){
             var cachecleaner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/cachecleaner");
              cachecleaner.del(
                function () {
             console.log("PhoneGap Plugin: CacheCleaner: callback success"); 
              window.location.href = "index.html";             
                },
                function () {
                  console.log("PhoneGap Plugin: CacheCleaner: callback error");
                }
              );
```